# Unable to use SQLite in VS2017 universal windows platform project

Tags: sqlite, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I try to use the SQLite in the VS2017 in a universal windows platform project. I follow the guidance to download the SQLite extension for VS2015 although my local machine environment is VS2017, maybe this is the root cause? Then I add the reference with SQLIte. After that I installed the SQLitePCL with nuget.

After the SQLite installed, I wanted to try to run a demo to see if it can work right. But I found I can't using the namespace (using  SQLite.Net.Attributes;) which it necessary for my demo.

I did some search about the SQLite and VS2017, But didn't found too much about such circumstances. So I want to know if anyone ever met such problem and How can your fix that?

Or it just unavailable to using SQLite in VS2017? If yes, can I complier a newest version about this?

Thanks everyone who can give me some reply or suggestion about this issue.

Comment: What is the version of your SQLitePCL ? I am using 3.8.7.2 and it gives me no such problem ? Have you tried updating it ?

Comment: My SQLitePCL version is 3.8.7.2 either. My issue is that I can't using that namespace...I though it is the problem of the SQLite extension.

Answer (score 0):

> But I found I can't using the namespace (using SQLite.Net.Attributes;)

It seems like [`SQLite.Net.Attributes`](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/tree/master/src/SQLite.Net/Attributes) is belong to the Nuget package [`SQLite.Net-PCL`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL/), not [`SQLitePCL`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLitePCL/), the one you are using. `SQLitePCL` does't contain `SQLite.Net.Attributes`. You may obtain the package that is not you attempt to use.

There're many Nuget packages for SQLite, some of them are older with long time no updating. For UWP app, I'd recommend you to follow **[this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases)** to use a SQLite database in a UWP app.

Comment: Thanks you so much! It was my mistake to install the SQLitePCL instead of the SQLite.Net-PCL.